# How to put my api body in messages for gifted chat

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

can anyone tell me?
I get an array of messages, through api, it contains id, body, owner name
"messages": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "createdAt": "2019-10-23T12:58:22.933Z",
      "body": "Hello",
    },
.....

How can I write it as an array for giftedchat, what would it be
"messages": [
    {
      "_id": "1",
      "createdAt": "2019-10-23T12:58:22.933Z",
      "text": "Hello",
    },
.....

And there are 10 messages, that is, how to iterate over to write values ​​from one array to another

Just for a flatlist, there goes render and selects, name: item.ownername, is there something similar that could be used for messages in gifted chat?

Comment: you can simply map messages array from your apicall  to the desired form of array for Gifted chat.Can you elaborate more for your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should map your array to get the same format as needed for GiftedChat

```
const newArray = messages.map(message => ({ _id: message.id, createdAt: message.createdAt, text: message.body, user: { _id: //user_id, name: //username } }))
```